# What use with this code, " protected $attributes = []; "?

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner of laravel. I read some information from the laravel's website, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#default-attribute-values, and it said that we can setup some default attributes in model. The detail what is said:

Default Attribute Values
If you would like to define the default values for some of your model's attributes, you may define an $attributes property on your model:

```php
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The model's default values for attributes.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $attributes = [
        'delayed' => false,
    ];
}
```

Now, i have created CRUD function in the laravel. And setting up with some example/default values in the database, it is "id"=1,"element1"="ABC","element2"="abc".
Finally, I find nothing in showing table.

```php
Database Table:
...
public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('cruds', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->string('element1');
      $table->string('element2');
  });
}
...
```

```php
Model:CRUD
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class crud extends Model
{
    protected $timestramp = false;
    protected $primarykey = "id";
    protected $attributes =[
        'id'        => 1,
        'element1'  => "ABC",
        'element2'  => "abc",
    ];
}
```

```php
View.blade.php
...
<tbody>
@foreach ($CRUDitems as $item)
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ ($item->$id) }}</th>
    <td>{{ ($item->$element1) }}</td>
    <td>{{ ($item->$element2) }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
...
```

```php
CRUDController.php
...
public function index()
  {
    $CRUDitems = crud::all();
    return view('CRUD.viewTable',compact('CRUDitems')) ;
  }
...
```

```php
web.php
<?php
Route::resource('/CRUD', 'CRUDController');
```

How do i do with i want to setup some default value?
thank you!

Comment: Seems you are trying to query your table before you actually saved anything there?

Comment: Have you saved any data? You have to make at least one object from your model and save it.

Comment: my database table is empty and i want to set some example/default data in laravel before using in the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make an object from your model. To do so (for test purpose) let's add a route like this:

```
Route::get('test', 'CRUDController@test');
```

And in your controller add a `test` method like this:

```
public function test(){
    $crud = new Crud();
    $crud->save();
}
```

You can also use `tinker` to test your code.

type `php artisan tinker` in command/console and then make a new instance of your model:

```
$crud = new App\Crud;
$crud->save();
```

Comment: my route is using "resource" type, how do i edit with it?
and also, the making a new instance of model mean places those code into the "crud" model, isn't it? But, it incurs error.

Comment: You can edit your route file and add the line I mentioned without changing your default resource route. I think it's better to do works in controller. The model does the basic works with database.